# Grouping JSON by values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, grouping

Using the Lever job posting API, I'm getting JSON results sorted by location, and I'm trying to figure out how to group all those results by "team" within the results, like the [Shopify](https://www.shopify.com/careers#work-at-shopify) careers page.

Here is the [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jAxXAo) and here is the [JSON](https://api.lever.co/v0/postings/leverdemo?group=location&mode=json)

I tried adding the following on line 38 of the codepen to try to grab the team values, but it's not outputting as expected (I'm getting one letter per line, which isn't helpful):

```
for (var x in _data[i].postings[j].categories.team)
```

I'm sure it's probably something super simple, but I'm definitely not a javascript guy. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Summarize and Group JSON object in Jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21874436/summarize-and-group-json-object-in-jquery)

Comment: Post your code and JSON sample in the question.

Comment: Put relevant code to avoid vote-down

Answer (score 52):

Assume , the JSON output is

```
outJSON = 
[ {
      team: "TeamA",
      name: "Ahmed",
      field3:"val3"
  }, 
{
      team: "TeamB",
      name: "Ahmed",
      field3:"val43"
  }, 
{
      team: "TeamA",
      name: "Ahmed",
      field3:"val55"
  }, 
]
```

Then  see the `groupBy` function in the DEMO below:

---

## DEMO :

```js
outJSON = [{
  team: "TeamA",
  name: "Ahmed",
  field3: "val3"
}, {
  team: "TeamB",
  name: "Ahmed",
  field3: "val43"
}, {
  team: "TeamA",
  name: "Ahmed",
  field3: "val55"
}]

var groupBy = function(xs, key) {
  return xs.reduce(function(rv, x) {
    (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
    return rv;
  }, {});
};
var groubedByTeam = groupBy(outJSON, 'team')
console.log(groubedByTeam);
```

Then , if you want to loop through categories (teams), get all categories in array  :

```
Object.keys(groubedByTeam) // return ["TeamA","TeamB"]
```

then :

```
Object.keys(groubedByTeam).forEach(function(category) {
    console.log(`Team ${category} has ${groubedByTeam[category].length} members : `);
        groubedByTeam[category].forEach(function(memb,i){
        console.log(`---->${i+1}. ${memb.name}.`)
    })
});
```

Comment: I'm sure that works great, but it is entirely way over my head without context. I'll try to ask some buddies so I can actually see how it works with the provided JSON. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, can you please write some explanation to help us understand better? thanks

Comment: xs.reduce is not a function

Comment: what if i want to apply group by using two fields