# Group JSON by key

Tags: javascript, json

I have structured JSON data as below:

```
[
    {
        "Month": "Jan"
        "Year": 2015,
        "Count": 15
    },
    {
        "Month": "Feb"
        "Year": 2015,
        "Count": 5
    },
    {
        "Month": "Jan"
        "Year": 2016,
        "Count": 25
    },
        {
        "Month": "Feb"
        "Year": 2016,
        "Count": 50
    }
]
```

I want to group the data using JavaScript to get the below output. Can someone help me with this?

```
[
    {
        "Month": "Jan"
        "Count_2015": 15,
        "Count_2016": 25
    },
    {
        "Month": "Feb"
        "Count_2015": 5,
        "Count_2016": 50
    }
]
```

Comment: Check out this question. it might be helpful
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38575721/grouping-json-by-values

Comment: Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).

Comment: Iterate over the JSON and as you do test for your conditions and add it all to a new JSON object. Obviously you'll have to create the keys from the value and it will require a bit of recursion.

Comment: Please post what you've tried and then ask why it doesn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grouping JSON by values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38575721/grouping-json-by-values)

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service. There are lots and lots of other similar questions around you could research to at least get a starting point. Then when you have real code problems ask questions then

Answer (score 1):

You can use `forEach()` loop and use one object as `thisArg` param.

```js
var data = [{"Month":"Jan","Year":2015,"Count":15},{"Month":"Feb","Year":2015,"Count":5},{"Month":"Jan","Year":2016,"Count":25},{"Month":"Feb","Year":2016,"Count":50}]  

var result = []
data.forEach(function(e, i) {
  if (!this[e.Month]) {
    this[e.Month] = {
      Month: e.Month,
      ['Count_' + e.Year]: e.Count
    }
    result.push(this[e.Month])
  } else {
    this[e.Month]['Count_' + e.Year] = e.Count
  }
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks Nenad. I will try this out.

Comment: Sorry everyone. I am relatively new to this and will make sure the next time I face an issue, i will word the question properly and given more clarity with what I have tried out and what issue I faced.

Comment: Nice solution - I prefer your answer. But you don't need the i arg, it's superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

```
var months = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
var result = [];
[].forEach.call(months, function(month) {
  var monthObj = {"Month": month};
  result.push(monthObj);
});
let mi, year, keystr
for (var i=0; i< data.length; i++) {
  var obj = data[i];
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
    var value = obj[key];
    switch (key) {
      case "Month":
        mi = months.indexOf(value);
        break;
      case "Year":
        year = value;
        break;
      case "Count":
        keystr = "Count_" + year.toString();
        resObj = result[mi];
        resObj[keystr] = value;
        break;
    }
  }
}
console.log(result);
```

Try it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/w13c5Lfx/)

Comment: In my version I tried to make sure the months displayed in chronological order in the result set, rather than presume on complete set for all months for each year, so if you processed "Sep" first, it would be first result...