# is it possible to group this kind array? [Javascript]

Tags: javascript

I made following Array.

I need to group items by categories.

Is it possible to group by category?

I am trying and thinking but too difficult.

Should I just change Array format to make simple?

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: apple,
        category: {
            name: 'fruit'
        }
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: orange,
        category: {
            name: 'frit'
        }
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: cucumber,
        category: {
            name: 'vegetable'
        }       
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: chicken,
        category: {
            name: 'meat'
        }       
    },
]
```

Result I want is

```
[
    {
        category: fruit,
        items: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: apple,
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: orange,
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        category: vegetable,
        items: [
            {
                id: 3,
                name: cucumber,
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        category: meat,
        items: [
            {
                id: 4,
                name: chicken,
            },
        ]
    },
]
```

thanks
thanks
thanks
thanks
thanks
thanks
thanks
thanks
thanks
thanks
thanks
thanks
thanks
thanks
thanks
thanks
thanks
thanks
thanks
thanks
thanks

Comment: This is *grouping*, not sorting. Also, it's not JSON, it's just a normal array.

Comment: @VLAZ thanks i will change names.

Comment: all you need to do is group them , not sort them, check this question in SO - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38575721/grouping-json-by-values

Comment: You can get a down vote for posting multiple thanks... just one is enough :-)

Comment: @NeonEmmanuel thanks for advice. I will care.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a method to go through you array and arrange the items by their category. Something like this:

```js
function groupByCategory (array) {
    let groupedArray = [];
    for (const item of array)
        if (item.category.name) {
            if (!groupedArray[category.name]) groupedArray[category.name] = [];
            groupedArray[category.name].push(item);
    }
    return groupedArray;
}
```