# how to Group json object based on id in the object

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodes

I need to group common objects to single with count,how to group the object based on the id in the object and how to add extra key with count in result.

```
 var a =[
{"name":"test","id":101,"price":100},
{"name":"test","id":101,"price":100},
{"name":"test3","id":103,"price":10},
{"name":"test2","id":102,"price":12},
]
```

output =

```
             [
                {"name":"test","id":101,"price":100,"qty":2},
                {"name":"test3","id":103,"price":10,"qty":1},
                {"name":"test2","id":102,"price":12,"qty":1},
            ]
```

Comment: Already answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38575721/grouping-json-by-values

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (certainly not the fastest but works ;):

```
let myarray = [
 {"name":"test","id":101,"price":100},
 {"name":"test","id":101,"price":100},
 {"name":"test3","id":103,"price":10},
 {"name":"test2","id":102,"price":12},
];

let groupedArray = myarray.reduce((acc, cur) => { 
  let foundIndex = acc.findIndex(a => a.id == cur.id); 
  if (foundIndex != -1){ 
     acc[foundIndex].qty += 1  
  } else {
    cur.qty = 1; acc.push(cur) 
  } 
  return acc;
}, []);

// groupedArray contains the grouped objects
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const a =[
    {"name":"test","id":101,"price":100},
    {"name":"test","id":101,"price":100},
    {"name":"test3","id":103,"price":10},
    {"name":"test2","id":102,"price":12},
];

const output = a.reduce((acc, nv, i, arr) => {
    const item = acc.find(e => e.id === nv.id);
    if(item) return acc;
    acc.push({ ...nv, count: arr.filter(e => e.id === nv.id)?.length });
    return acc;
}, []);
```